# Java Regex: replacing a specific kind of url in a string?

Tags: java, regex

Sample input:

`"http://bits.wikimedia.org/w/extensions-1.17/MobileFrontend/stylesheets/webkit.css"`

my attempt: `"http://.*?/stylesheets/webkit.css"` does not find any matches

The part of the url between `"http://"` and `"webkit.css"` is variable

Thanks!

My bad, I was using Java's replace() function as opposed to replaceFirst() or replaceAll()

Comment: Are you escaping your periods appropriately?  And how are you trying to replace a String or Strings here? Can you show more code?

Comment: What code are you using? Your regex is really simple and should work. @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, even if he doesn't, it should match anyway (though it would indeed be better to escape them)

Comment: @Vache: yup, you're right, as I've just tested them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution **using groups**:

```
String input = "http://bits.wikimedia.org/w/extensions-1.17/" + 
               "MobileFrontend/stylesheets/webkit.css";

String replacement = "example.com";

String result = input.replaceAll("(http://).*?(/stylesheets/webkit\\.css)",
                "$1" + replacement + "$2");
```

Result will equal `http://example.com/stylesheets/webkit.css`.

---

Another option **using look arounds**:

```
String result = input.replaceAll("(?<=http://).*(?=/stylesheets/webkit\\.css)",
                                 replacement);
```

which says "replace everything in between `http://` and `/stylesheets/webkit.css` with `replacement`.